# Call to a member function details() on null?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**My code is:**

```
$user = User::create([
   'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
 ]);

$user_details = [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'lastname' => $request->lastname,
            'secondname' => $request->secondname,
            'inn' => $request->inn,
            'fincode' => $request->fincode,
        ];

$user->details()->create($user_details);
```

**Model User** is:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserDetails::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

**UserDetails** model is:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserDetails extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'enterprise';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'lastname', 'secondname', 'address', 'inn', 'fincode'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your `$user` has not been persisted, hence having the error, in your case `$user` is null, that's why you cannot call `details` on `null` object. Make sure that you use all the required fields on your user.

You might be missing the `fillable` array in the `User` model if the one that you shared is the full content, then add this:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'email', 'password'];
```

Comment: I have: `  protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'email_verified_at', 'password', 'status',
    ];`

Comment: can you `dd($user)` after you create it and make sure that it is persisted?